# How do I make one event listener to multiple text fields in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, swt

I have a shell with several Text Widgets.

Each one corresponds to a different `String` object which saves its input for later processing (after the widget itself is disposed).

I'm using a `ModifyListener` to update the string each time the text changes, as seen in this simple example:

```
    String clientNametext = "";
    Text clientName = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
    clientName.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

        @Override
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent paramModifyEvent)
        {
            clientNametext = clientName.getText();

        }
    });
```

However, I have many such `Text` fields and I would like to clean up the code, and - instead of attaching a new inner class listener per field - create a single `ModifyListener`, which will then be attached to all of them, and modify the correct variable according to which field change triggered the event.

The issue is, the `ModifyEvent` itself doesn't seem to hold such information, or any way to uniquely identify which text field changed.

**EDIT:** It is very important for me to have only one Listener which handles all cases, if possible.

Answers with "use other types of fields and listening objects" are welcome, in case `ModifyEvent` cannot uniquely identify the exact widget where it occurred, without using some crazy logic with mapping Object IDs or whatnot.

Comment: What about `Text text = (Text) paramModifyEvent.widget;`, and then `clientNametext = text.getText();`?

Comment: Text is not a Swing component. And what is a ModifyListener?

Comment: Have you tried a simple innerclass that implements ActionListener ?

Comment: @LuxxMiner, I like your proposal. taking the text as a widget from the event - is it possible to somehow know if it's the 'clientName' text instead of "instance of Text with ID 11300" ?

Answer (score 4):

#### Wrap the entire behavior in a single class.

Right now you have a bunch of pairs of `String` and `Text` objects. Roll them all into one class:

```
public class ListeningText {
  private String clientNametext = "";
  private final Text clientName = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);

  public ListeningText() {
    clientName.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
      @Override
      public void modifyText(ModifyEvent paramModifyEvent)
      {
        clientNametext = clientName.getText();
      }
    });
  }

  public Text getText() {
    return Text;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Then, use it like this. You only create one field item, a `ListeningText`, instead of two, a `String` and a `Text`. You would use it like this:

```
public class YourComponent {
  ListeningText text;
  ListeningText anotherText;
  // etc.

  public void initComponents() {
    // add them like this:
    text = new ListeningText();
    container.add(text.getComponent());
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    // get the value like this:
    System.out.println(text.getValue()); // or whatever
  }
}
```

Note that this solution doesn't create a "single" `ModifyListener`, but I think what you wanted was to [prevent code duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you don't care that there are still many such objects. It would be much harder to only have one object, and then write it to update the corresponding field; this way should accomplish the clean code goal without really complicated code.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
this will make the code more clean, however I think it will still create a new Listener for each Text field.

what I would like is one listener to handle all text fields, and that listener needs to know based on the triggering event, which Text changed and which String it needs to update.

Comment: @user2406322 I explained that at the bottom. You are completely correct, however, the code to maintain such a `Map`ping (that's a hint for how to do it) is unnecessarily complicated. Java does well with lots of small, helper objects such as this one, and I don't recommend it.

Comment: thanks again.
I do have only a handful of these text fields (6), so maintaining a Map shouldn't be a problem.
the entire question ultimately comes down to "what would be the map key", because the Event itself doesn't know how to tell me "the Widget that changed this time, was 'clientText1'".

if Java can handle multiple (6) listener classes created, I guess the solution is like you said to make the code more visually pleasant.

ideally though, I would like to have only one listener.
maybe it'd be harder to code first time, but it would be easier to maintain afterwards.

Comment: This is my point. Figuring out "what should the map key be?" "How do I create an interface for the `Map` that's easy to use and maintainable?" and other questions are just added complexity; added complexity means *less maintainability, not more*. You're right to want to reduce the code duplication, but the number of objects is trivial; **six extra objects**. [Keep It Simple Stupid](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/178294/88986), as it were.

Comment: @user2406322 By the way, if I've helped you don't forget you can mark this answer as correct by selecting the hollow checkmark next to the voting buttons on the left side of the question.

Comment: you helped a lot but I do not think my question is answered fully yet. which is why I am going to vote it up but not mark the checkmark yet.
I do indeed want it all in one place. one Listener.
if that's impossible to do with this specific type of field and event, I am willing to use other objects. as long as the event itself will be able to tell me **where** the change happened, so I can handle all cases in one place.

Comment: @igorT, in the `modifyText` method, you could get the source of the event and check which text field is that source. A lot of *if..else* and you are good to go